# Yank words separated only by periods

Tags: vim

I have a line like this in a file

> ```
> <echo>The app vendor is... app.server.name</echo>
> ```

With the cursor over the 'r' in 'server', how can I yank 'app.server.name' without going into visual mode, or without having to guess the number of words to yank.

`yiw` will only yank the word inbetween the periods.

Comment: This title is misleading, you're not actually looking to yank between "whitespace"

Comment: So, not only is the title misleading, but you also accepted, over 2 years later, an answer that is incompatible with either the title or the question wording. Would you please consider fixing your question?

Comment: How do you figure that sehe? I don't want to yank between white space, I want to "Yank words separated only by periods". Also I only changed the accepted answer after this question popped up in my notifications, as someone had recently tagged it as "nice question".

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
Byt<
```

`B` (to get you to the beginning of the punctuated word)

`yt<` (to yank forward, up to but excluding the "<").

Answer (score 12):

### 1. Quick and dirty: include dots in 'word' matching

```
 :se iskeyword+=46
```

Now <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> will do what you want :)

### 2. Proper solution: define a text object

As Benoit mentions, the above *might* be side effects that you don't want<sup>1</sup>

[In an earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7292052/vim-select-inside-dots/7292271#7292271) ( [vim: select inside dots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7292052/vim-select-inside-dots/7292271#7292271)) I describe how to definte a text object to select inside dots (shown below). You could use that as a basis to define a similar *text object* that selects words including dots:

***This doesn't require any changes to the `iskeyword` setting*** :)

> ```
> xnoremap <silent>.  f.oT.o
> xnoremap <silent>a. f.oF.o
> xnoremap <silent>i. t.oT.o
>
> onoremap <silent>.  :<C-u>exec 'normal v' . v:count1 . '.'<CR>
> onoremap <silent>a. :<C-u>exec 'normal v' . v:count1 . 'a.'<CR>
> onoremap <silent>i. :<C-u>exec 'normal v' . v:count1 . 'i.'<CR>
> ```
>
> Examples for the following buffer contents (*cursor on the letter `w`*):
>
> ```
> someobject.some-property-with-hyphens.SUB.otherproperty
> ```
>
> - <kbd>v</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> selects `some-property-with-hyphens.` in visual mode
> - <kbd>v</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> selects `.some-property-with-hyphens.` in visual mode
> - <kbd>v</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> selects `some-property-with-hyphens` in visual mode
>
> Motions can be chained and accept a `count`:
>
> - <kbd>v</kbd><kbd>.</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> selects `some-property-with-hyphens.SUB.` in visual mode
> - <kbd>v</kbd><kbd>2.</kbd> *also* selects `some-property-with-hyphens.SUB.` in visual mode
> - <kbd>v</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> selects `.some-property-with-hyphens.SUB.` in visual mode
> - <kbd>v</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> selects `some-property-with-hyphens.SUB` in visual mode
>
> You can use the operators as operators to any editing command:
>
> - <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> results in `someobject.SUB.otherproperty`
> - <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>.</kbd><kbd>shortname</kbd> results in `someobject.shortname.SUB.otherproperty`
> - <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>.</kbd><kbd>get("</kbd> results in `someobject.get("otherproperty`
>
> It doesn't matter *where* in a 'dot-delimited-identifier' the cursor is to start with. Note that for convenience, all visual mode mappings position the cursor at the end of the selection (so you can do continue extending the selection by e.g. `%` and other motions).

---

<sup>1</sup> see a bit of background information here: [vim: select inside dots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7292052/vim-select-inside-dots/7292271#7292271)

Comment: but it can also have side-effects probably.

Comment: @Benoit: I addressed your concerns. I also linked to [my earlier answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7292052/vim-select-inside-dots/7292271#7292271) that defined an [operator-mapping](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#%3amap-operator) to define a custom _text object_ :) Hope that helps