# How can I include periods when selecting a word in vim?

Tags: vim

Let's say I'm calling a method on an object in my code like

```
if abc.xyz then foo
```

My cursor is on the 'c' in 'abc' and I want to change abc.xyz to something else. If I type `ciw` I'll be replacing only 'abc'. What can I use instead of `iw` so that it selects the entire 'abc.xyz'?

Comment: `2ciw`, to select two words?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/7914019.

Comment: @MarcB good call! actually it's `3ciw`, the period counts as a word.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `W` to separate words only with whitespace characters, it will select the whole string:

```
ciW
```

Comment: awesome! That's gonna make my life much easier. I do have another slightly more complicated scenario I'm wondering about: same as above but the code is `if (abc.xyz == "123")` and I don't want to select the open-paren

Comment: @ChrisDoyle: For that new scenario look at [perreal's](http://stackoverflow.com/users/390913/perreal) answer.

Answer (score 6):

Include the `.` in the `iskeyword` [option](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_05.html):

```
set iskeyword=@,48-57,_,192-255,.
```

Comment: Better just add to the default: `:set iskeyword+=.`; and I wouldn't set this globally, but (with `:setlocal`) only for certain filetypes (in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/<filetype>.vim`).