# vim call a function from inside a vmap

Tags: vim

I have created a vmap text object for selecting the text of a single LaTeX \item:

```
vmap im ?\\item<CR>o/\\item\\|\\end{itemize}<CR>b$
```

But this has the annoying feature that I lose my current search term. I have read that search terms are restored when the search happens inside a function call, so I wanted to convert the map to just call a function that would do the searches:

```
function! ItemizeTextObject()
  ?\\item
  normal o
  /\\item|\\end{itemize}
  normal b$
endfunction

vmap in :call ItemizeTextObject()<CR>
```

Unfortunately, this does not work: I get an error ("Pattern not found: \item|\end{itemize}"), no text at all is selected, and a new line is inserted below the line my cursor is on. I tried several variations of this, and had no success.

I think the basic problem is that I have to preserve the visual mode when calling the function (the `o` in my command should switch to the other end of the selection, but it inserts a new line instead), but I don't know how.

*Update:*

I try to get the following behaviour: In a text like this:

```
\begin{itemize}
  \item lorem ipsum...
  \item piece of text I want to select,
   the *CURSOR* is here, and there is more text
   that follows
  \item lorem ipsum...
\end{itemize}
```

I want to hit `vin`, and then the text block in the middle should be selected:

```
  \item piece of text I want to select,
   the *CURSOR* is here, and there is more text
   that follows
```

that means the text from the beginning of the previous `\item`, until but not including the next `\item` or `\end{itemize}`.

Comment: an issue might be the missing escape for `|`: `/\\item\|\\end{itemize}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used the doc on `operatorfunc` to come up with the following, which should be (close to) what you want<sup>1</sup>:

```
function! ItemizeTextObject(type, ...)
    let sel_save = &selection
    let &selection = "inclusive"
    let reg_save = @@

    if a:0  " Invoked from Visual mode, use '< and '> marks.
        silent! 1,+1?\\item
        norm v | " use V for linewise visual mode
        "" use V for linewise visual mode:
        "norm V
        silent! /\\item\|\\end{itemize}
    "elseif a:type == 'line'
    "elseif a:type == 'block'
    else
       silent! 1,+1?\\item
       norm v
       silent! /\\item
    endif

    norm b$

    let &selection = sel_save
    let @@ = reg_save
endfunction

silent! unmap in

xnoremap <silent> in :<C-U>call ItemizeTextObject(visualmode(), 1)<CR>
```

If you want the mapping in both *visual* and *select* modes, you should use `vnoremap`

Notes of things to address:

- you can now implement the motion from another mode (fill in the branches in the function)
- if `wrapscan` is on, no search should wrap (perhaps temporarily set `nowrapscan`?)
- you might want to make the operator repeating so you can *extend the selection* by saying `vininin` (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/7292271/85371 for an example)
- it looks like you want 'linewise' behaviour (due to `b$`?)

  - consider using `norm V` (see comment)

---

**Edit** I compared the behaviour with this simple mapping:

```
xnoremap <silent>in ?\\item<CR>o/\\item\\|\\end{itemize}<CR>b$
```

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Disclaimer: I don't know LateX</sub>

Comment: ah fixed a leftover bug - **now** it does what you describe (sorry for the copy/paste mistake)

Comment: Could you explain the `1,+1` part of the searches? I couldn't find anything in the vim help files.