# Is it possible to determine in an operator-pending mapping whether the motion will be linewise, blockwise or normal?

Tags: vim

When declaring a mapping with `omap` or `onoremap` i would like to be able to handle the case where the motion will be blockwise, linewise or standard.

For example let's consider the following block:

```
abcd
efgh
ijkl
mnop
```

Cursor is on the letter f. Suppose that I define an operator map from `K` to `:normal! vjl` (go to letter k).

```
onoremap K :normal! vjl<cr>
```

Interestingly enough when I run `dvK`, `dK`, `d^VK` I get respectively

```
abcd   abcd   abcd
el     el     eh
mnop   mnop   il
              mnop
```

But when I run `dVK` it won't work, I get exactly the same as with `dvK`.

I tried to use `visualmode()` (mapping defined as `@=visualmode()<cr>jl<cr>` but this does not work. It seems that the return value of this function is not immediately affected when you use `v`, `V` or CTRL-V in operator-pending mode.

Does anyone have a clue please?
Thank you

Comment: When you start a visual selection you can change it to the other types of visual selections by hitting their corresponding command (`<S-v>` -> `v` -> `<C-v>` -> `v` -> whatever). Is it possible that you start a line-wise visual selection with the `V` in `dVK` but change its type to character-wise with the `v` in `vjl`?

Comment: @romainl: you are right! but it does not explain why it behaves differently for V.

Comment: Do you want to obtain two lines with `abcd` and `mnop`?

Comment: @romainl: yes exactly. And if I remove the `v` from the mapping it works.

Comment: Yes, if you change your mapping to `Vjl` it's `dvK` that doesn't work anymore.

Comment: What is the output you want / would expect as a result of dVk?  I'd like to help solve.

Comment: @kikuchiyo, I would like it to work linewise, therefore it should delete two lines, and I should hage `abcd`,`mnop`.

Comment: Cool.  It's the original mapping.  I think it over-rides your 'V'.  If you do a onoremap K :normal! Vjl<cr>, then you get the result you want.  As romainl notes, however, dvK no longer works.  For a little proof of concept of v overriding V, you can do this manually and note the change from '-- VISUAL LINE --' to '-- VISUAL --'.  I think you got this licked by just leaving the 'v' out of onoremap K :normal! vjl<cr>.  You could either make three seperate mappings for the three modes or else use a function.  If you want to try a function let me know and I'll try to help.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve what you desired, you can simply define

```
onoremap K :<c-u>normal! jl<cr>
```

Note this motion, as formed by a ex-command, is always characterwise (see `:h movement`

Then you can freely use `dv`, or `dV`, or `d^V` to force the motion to be another type and get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I've written some answers on operator pending mappings. In [one of them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356572/vim-call-a-function-from-inside-a-vmap/8357533#8357533)<sup>1</sup> I sketched an outline of a function that should handle the various cases (char,line,block wise selections) according to the docs:

```
 g@{motion}     Call the function set by the 'operatorfunc' option.
        The '[ mark is positioned at the start of the text
        moved over by {motion}, the '] mark on the last
        character of the text.
        The function is called with one String argument:
            "line"  {motion} was |linewise|
            "char"  {motion} was |characterwise|
            "block" {motion} was |blockwise-visual|
        Although "block" would rarely appear, since it can
        only result from Visual mode where "g@" is not useful.
        {not available when compiled without the |+eval|
        feature}
```

Here is an example that counts the number of spaces with `<F4>`: >

```
nmap <silent> <F4> :set opfunc=CountSpaces<CR>g@
vmap <silent> <F4> :<C-U>call CountSpaces(visualmode(), 1)<CR>

function! CountSpaces(type, ...)
  let sel_save = &selection
  let &selection = "inclusive"
  let reg_save = @@

  if a:0  " Invoked from Visual mode, use '< and '> marks.
    silent exe "normal! `<" . a:type . "`>y"
  elseif a:type == 'line'
    silent exe "normal! '[V']y"
  elseif a:type == 'block'
    silent exe "normal! `[\<C-V>`]y"
  else
    silent exe "normal! `[v`]y"
  endif

  echomsg strlen(substitute(@@, '[^ ]', '', 'g'))

  let &selection = sel_save
  let @@ = reg_save
endfunction
```

<sup>1</sup> [vim call a function from inside a vmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356572/vim-call-a-function-from-inside-a-vmap/8357533#8357533)

Comment: I granted the bounty because I feel that this answer is close to it (and there was no other answer). But if this can be useful to define a new, arbitrary command that will expect any motion, I fail to see how I can use it to define a new, arbitrary motion that might be either blockwise, linewise, or characterwise. Could you expand please?

Comment: Possibly useful / of interest: https://github.com/kana/vim-operator-user