# vim run series of commands (or a function) on selection

Tags: vim

I have a series of vim commands that write the selected block to a temporary file, run a function (knitcite) on that file, and then read in another file:

```
w! ~/.vbuf <CR> 
!knitcite ~/.vbuf ~/.vbuf <CR> 
r ~/.vbuf <CR>
```

If I've selected a block of text in visual mode before running the first command, it becomes

```
:'<,'>w! ~/.vbuf <CR>
```

passing the selected contents to the file, as I need.  I can put this into a simple vim function in my .vimrc, but cannot figure out how to pass the contents of the visual selection to the function.  If this were a single command instead of three commands, I could do this with a visual map, but not sure how to do it with three commands.  something like:

```
command knitcite call Knitcite()
func! Knitcite()  
exec "w! ~/.vbuf <CR>"
exec "!knitcite ~/.vbuf ~/.vbuf <CR> "
exec "r ~/.vbuf <CR>"
func
```

but this doesn't get any data passed in from the visual block.  I guess I need to give an argument to my Knitcite function but cannot figure out what it would be. (Seems that this might be related to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356572/vim-call-a-function-from-inside-a-vmap) but I couldn't figure out how to generalize from that answer.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest thing to do would be to use as a filter:

```
:'<,'>!knitcite
```

If `knitcite` doesn't work in filter mode (often it uses `-` to signify stdin as a filename, other options may apply) you could wrap it in a shell script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
tmpname="/tmp/$(basename "$0").tmp$RANDOM"

trap "rm -f '$tmpname'" ERR INT EXIT
knitcite <(cat) "$tmpname"
cat "$tmpname"
```

---

Otherwise, it looks like you want to replace the visual selection with the output:

```
:'<,'>w! ~/.vbuf
:'<,'>d _
:silent! !knitcite ~/.vbuf ~/.vbuf.out
:'<-1r ~/.vbuf.out
```

***Note***

1. the use of a separate temporary file for the output: *otherwise, trouble may arise on most platforms, where the truncation of the output file might happen before the input has been read!*
2. the use of the *black hole register* (`"_`) with the `:delete` command to avoid clobbering any registers

Comment: Thanks for providing both the direct answer to the question and the suggestion of a better way by wrapping with a shell script.  Fantastic.

Comment: @cboettig Thanks. Note I just removed superfluous quoting from the signal trap