# In vim, how do I make a custom word boundary motion?

Tags: search, vim, cpu-word, motion, boundary

As I understand, `w` recognizes word boundaries by splitting text into 3 groups:

1) characters that are specified in the `iskeyword` setting (alphabetic, digits, and underscore)

2) other non-printable characters (symbols)

3) whitespace characters

Each time you press `w` it goes to the next group 1 or group 2.  I'd like to customize it so it only goes to the next group 1, jumping over "symbol words".

What almost works is this:

`nnoremap w /\k\+<CR>`

which uses the `iskeyword` character class `\k`.  But it is ugly because it simulates me performing a search, which changes my highlighting, clutters my search history, and who knows what else.  Is there way to make this work "cleanly" like the `w` command normally is?

Comment: I don't quite follow what you want. Does `W` help? It has two groups of characters: whitespace, and non-whitespace, so it always goes to the first character after the next whitespace.

Comment: No, it doesn't quite work:  `W` lumps the symbol characters together with alphabetic characters.  What I want is to, effectively, lump symbols with whitespace, so that symbols are skipped while still creating word boundaries.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for [operator pending mode](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#%3amap-operator), a.k.a `xmap, smap` and family.

I have done some examples of these [in other answers on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A85371+%5Bvim%5D+operator):

The most relevant example might be

- [vim: select inside dots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7292052/vim-select-inside-dots/7292271#7292271)

You will also find some techniques that are similar and might be useful for you

Comment: I remember that one. Great answer.

Comment: Making it a proper motion for operators is great, and that SO answer taught me some new things.  But what is really making me unhappy is simulating "me performing a search" to move around, and I would have to do that to define my corresponding `xmap` and `omap`.

Comment: @Nuno: For the record, the docs say that searching from inside a vimscript (function) will **not** influence your 'current' search pattern, search history etc. (Anyways, any _other_ side effects could simply be restored in that same function)

Comment: How do I define a function which moves the cursor to the next `/\k\+` search result?

Comment: This, `:search('\m\k\+', 'W')`, will move the cursor to the next `/\k\+` search results. As a bonus it will not mess up your search history or highlighting. See `:h search()` for more options.

Comment: @PeterRincker Thanks!  If you post this as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

I may not be much help here .. I don't even know what `\k` means in this context, but you can solve the two immediate problems you present:

```
nnoremap w /\k\+<CR>:nohl<CR>:call histdel("search", -1)<CR>
```

It's ugly and the highlighting may flicker, but maybe this will point you in the right direction.